# Trying to append a new row to the first row in a the table body with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Having trouble appending a new row to the first row (the header row) in the table body ().

my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup  

soup = BeautifulSoup(open('page_content.xml'), 'html.parser')

# append a row to the first row in the table body
row = soup.find('tbody').find('tr')
row.append(soup.new_tag('tr', text='New Cell'))

print(row)
```

the output:

```
<tr>
<th>Version</th>
<th>Jira</th>
<th colspan="1">Date/Time</th>
<tr text="New Cell"></tr></tr>
```

what the output should be:

```
<tr>
<th>Version</th>
<th>Jira</th>
<th colspan="1">Date/Time</th>
</tr>
<tr text="New Cell"></tr>
```

the full xml file is:

```
<h1>Rental Agreement/Editor</h1>
<table class="wrapped">
<colgroup>
<col/>
<col/>
<col/>
</colgroup>
<tbody>
<tr>
<th>Version</th>
<th>Jira</th>
<th colspan="1">Date/Time</th>
<tr text="New Cell"></tr></tr>
<tr>
<td>1.0.1-0</td>
<td>ABC-1234</td>
<td colspan="1">
<br/>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<p class="auto-cursor-target">
<br/>
</p>
```

Comment: `.find('tr')` that one is making you add segments in the `tr` tag because your `row` variable is the `tr` tag  and `.append` adds the new cell tag inside it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.insert_after`:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = """
<table>
<tr>
<th>Version</th>
<th>Jira</th>
<th colspan="1">Date/Time</th>
</tr>

<tr>
<td> something else </td>
</tr>
</table>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")

row = soup.select_one("tr:has(th)")
row.insert_after(soup.new_tag("tr", text="New Cell"))

print(soup.prettify())
```

Prints:

```html
<table>
 <tr>
  <th>
   Version
  </th>
  <th>
   Jira
  </th>
  <th colspan="1">
   Date/Time
  </th>
 </tr>
 <tr text="New Cell">
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>
   something else
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

---

EDIT: If you want to insert arbitrary HTML code, you can try:

```py
what_to_insert = BeautifulSoup(
    '<tr param="xxx">This is new <b>text</b></tr>', "html.parser"
)

row.insert_after(what_to_insert)
```

Comment: Thank you, that did work! but do you know how to get bs4 to format it like this `<td> new cell </td>` instead of `<td> text=new cell </td>`? The API that i'm pushing this to will display empty cells if the format is like `text=`

Comment: @aphexlog See my edit.